# Use of tense to express frequency

Tags: tense

I'd like to know if I am right about these two sentences:

> He was expelled because he had been misbehaving.

This means he misbehaved on several occasions, probably over a period of time.

> He was expelled because he had misbehaved.

This means he misbehaved once, or a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous tenses can have the effect of indicating that an action was repeated over a period of time. Compare "He jumped" with "He was jumping".

So your understanding is correct here. The first sentence suggests a period misbehaviour (perhaps repeated misbehaviour), the second sentence suggests a single act.